# How to exclude substring in Elasticsearch regexp

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to write an elasticsearch regexp that excludes elements that have a key that contains a substring, let's say in the title of books.

The [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) suggest that a substring can be excluded with the following snippet:

`@&~(foo.+)      # anything except string beginning with "foo"`

However, in my case, I've tried to create such a filter and failed.

```
  {
    query: {
      constant_score: {
        filter: {
          bool: {
            filter: query_filters,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    size: 1_000,
  }


def query_filters
  [
    { regexp: { title: "@&~(red)" } },
    # goal: exclude titles that start with "Red" 
  ]
end
```

I've used other regexp in the same query filter that have worked, so I don't think there's a bug in the way the regexp is being passed to ES.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update:

I found a workaround:

Comment: i think you have mssed  ".*" from you regular expression ...

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I found a workaround: I can add a `must_not` clause to the filter.

```
  {
    query: {
      constant_score: {
        filter: {
          bool: {
            filter: query_filters,
            must_not: must_not_filters,
          },
        },
      },
    },
        size: 1_000,
  }

def must_not_filters
   [ { regexp: { title: "red.*" } } ]
end
```

Still curious if there's another idea for the original regex though